# DatePipe in Angular returns incorrect results

Tags: angular

My local time zone is IST, which is 5 hours, 30 minutes ahead of UTC.

I am creating Date as below:

```js
this.date1original = new Date(2023,2,2);
this.date1 = this.datePipe.transform(this.date1original,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
```

Template:

```html
<h1>Date1</h1>
<section>
  <label>Original: new Date(2023,2,2)</label><br />{{ date1original }}
  <br />
  <label>datePipe:</label> <br />{{ date1 }}
</section>
```

Output:

[image]

Date returned by `Date()` has "00:00:00" in local time zone. The date in UTC is `2023-03-01T18:30:00` as can be seen below

[image]

Why does DatePipe's transform() method return "12:00:00" as time component? It does not seem to corelate with either local or UTC time zone.

Minimal reproducible example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepipe-in-component-u7o25d?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

Date pipe also as timezone and locale parameters.
You can override the `DatePipe` locale with `LOCALE_ID` InjectionToken and since Angular v15 `DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` InjectionToken for the timezone and dateFormat.

```
providers: [
{ provide: DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { dateFormat: 'shortDate', timezone: '+0530'}}
]
```

Since the project you linked is using Angular 6 you can’t use `DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS` to override timezone globally. So you might use the pipe parameters directly like so:

```
this.date1original = new Date(2023,2,2);
this.datePipe.transform(this.date1original,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss’, ‘+0530’);
```

`+0530` represent the India Standard Time

See: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 1):

> Why does DatePipe's transform() method return "12:00:00" as time component?

From [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

> hh    Numeric: 2 digits + zero padded 01, 12

With `hh` format for hour field, we get 12 hour format and it should be used with `a` to understand whether it is 'AM' or 'PM'.

```
this.date1 = this.datePipe.transform(this.date1original,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a');
```

returns

```
2023-03-02 12:00:00 AM
```

However, what I needed was the hour to be 24 hour format, so `HH` must be used instead.

```
this.date1 = this.datePipe.transform(this.date1original,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
```

returns

```
2023-03-02 00:00:00
```